# Nodejs and loading large GeoJSON file, for searching through?

Tags: node.js, parsing, geojson

I am trying to load a large GeoJSON file into my program, but I am now running into an 'out of memory' crash on my dev server (wasn't an issue on my portable), with the failure being:

```
Security context: 0x2a7393fcfb51 <JS Object>
    1: parse [native json.js:62] [pc=0x25e952e638ef] (this=0x2a7393fc9111 <a JSON with map 0xb4bfd40a0e1>,C=0x3e8116304201 <Very long string[64906954]>,w=0x2a7393f04381 <undefined>)
    2: arguments adaptor frame: 1->2
    3: loadGeoJson [/home/myuser/myproject/node/geo-locations.js:26] [pc=0x25e952f451ff] (this=0x362211a62d19 <a GeoLocations with map 0x3e0b88b2b5b1>...
FATAL ERROR: Committing semi space failed. Allocation failed - process out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x10a08dc [node]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportApiFailure(char const*, char const*) [node]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [node]
 5: v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 6: v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, char const*, char const*, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 7: v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedArray(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
 8: v8::internal::JsonParser<false>::ParseJsonArray() [node]
 9: v8::internal::JsonParser<false>::ParseJsonValue() [node]
10: v8::internal::JsonParser<false>::ParseJsonArray() [node]
11: v8::internal::JsonParser<false>::ParseJsonValue() [node]
12: v8::internal::JsonParser<false>::ParseJsonArray() [node]
13: v8::internal::JsonParser<false>::ParseJsonValue() [node]
14: v8::internal::JsonParser<false>::ParseJsonObject() [node]
15: v8::internal::JsonParser<false>::ParseJsonValue() [node]
16: v8::internal::JsonParser<false>::ParseJsonObject() [node]
17: v8::internal::JsonParser<false>::ParseJsonValue() [node]
18: v8::internal::JsonParser<false>::ParseJsonArray() [node]
19: v8::internal::JsonParser<false>::ParseJsonValue() [node]
20: v8::internal::JsonParser<false>::ParseJsonObject() [node]
21: v8::internal::JsonParser<false>::ParseJsonValue() [node]
22: v8::internal::JsonParser<false>::ParseJson() [node]
23: v8::internal::JsonParser<false>::Parse(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>) [node]
24: v8::internal::Runtime_ParseJson(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
25: 0x25e9525092a7
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The code being called that cause this issue is as follows:

```
JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filepath,"utf-8"))
```

I have tried breaking the lines in two, but since I have done that the crash hasn't occurred, making it hard to debug. In the meantime, I want to see if there is a better way of dealing with trying to load a GeoJSON file, to be able to look through the entries?

Essentially what I am doing is loading a GeoJSON file and searching to find if a Point is within a polygon. I have considered simply throwing this into MongoDB, but I am dealing with file contents that are semi-transient.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing the max memory limit in node?  The default is 512 mb.  You could do something like this to increase it to 1024 mb (or more depending on the size of your geoJson).

node --max-old-space-size=1024 script.js

Comment if this does not fix the issue, since there are other solutions possible as well.

Comment: It seems to do the job, though I would be curious as to what other solutions you had in mind.

Comment: Not loading the entire file into memory was the other option.  You could use a node stream to read in chunks of the file into memory, but this may not be useful depending on how you are using the geoJSON file.